DLL Load Failed while executing the imported module
Error Message:
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causessdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.File "C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core_init.py", line 59, in core_select_libmod = importlib.import(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1285, in importFile "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_importFile "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_loadFile "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlockedFile "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlockedFile "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_moduleFile "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removedFile "C:\Users\Tarun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 28, in <module>from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Try to re-install dependencies and framework itself but not resolved

Have you tried looking at this link
